# How to create a C++ console application in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I want to create console application in C++ with Visual Studio 2017. In all other tutorials it says to make a project by going to `File` > `New` > `Project` > `Win32` > `Win32 Console Application` but when I choose to make a new project the only template is a `Blank Solution`. I believe I need to install the template but I am not sure how to. Please Help.

Comment: A blank solution should default to console.

Comment: VS consists of many components, which can be installed separately. You didn't choose C++ development during installation, probably. Rerun the installer to revisit those choices. Also, you may need to install an SDK, though I'm not sure with that version.